# Как правильно построчно отнять значения из разных таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Как построчно выбрать значения в таблице `trans.balans` от которых нужно отнять значения в таблице `trans_log.kolichestvo`, где`trans.id = trans_log.id_trans`.
В таблице `trans_log` может быть несколько одинаковых `trans.id`, нужно взять последнее по столбцу `trans_log.time`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так:

```
select A.*,
       A.balans - ifnull(
         (
          select B.kolichestvo
            from trans_log B
           where B.id_trans=A.id
           order by B.time desc limit 1
         ), 0)
  from trans A
```